# access intranet webservice using python

Tags: python, web-services, suds, intranet

I need to access webservice under intranet.

I tried suds-jurko, under internet, it works well.

But it doesn't work under intranet, because it always try to open "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" and "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" which can't be opend under intranet.

Please tell me how can I do this job, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use zeep instead.

Zeep 3.4 compatible with Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and PyPy.

Zeep 4 compatible with Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and PyPy.